# Issues with SDK version when importing C# project into Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a visual studio project I am trying to import that is causing me issues. I am getting the following error message when I try and load the project:

```
error  : The project file cannot be opened by the project system, because it is missing some critical imports or the referenced SDK cannot be found.

Detailed Information:
Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the installed version.
```

So there are a few issues with this, number 1 being that there is no global.json file anywhere as far as I can tell nor is the project built using .NET Core (it's built with .NET framework 4.7.2). I have a .csproj file which I think might be causing the issues as it has the following lines:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I have other projects where the .csproj file has no mention of the SDK version at all and so I tried to delete the SKD element entirely from the XML element however this did not work either.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 7.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and can anyone explain how to rectify so that I can load the project into visual studio? Also is there a way to remove the SDK element so this wont happen if I try and move the project again?

Comment: What version of visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 running on Windows 7

Comment: What is your current project? Winform, WPF，asp.net app?

Comment: Its a library. Ties into a basic console application.

Comment: If it is a library, I suggest that you can add the dll as a reference to use the library.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to do this, I haven't been able to load the project at all into visual studio so I haven't been able to build it yet. Should there be a dll somewhere anyway?

Comment: As usual, the dll's place should be project\bin\debug\somedll.dll.